# For the Charger feat, is it possible to move at least 10 feet in a straight line while staying within an enemy's reach?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, movement, reach, charge

The Charger feat lets you make a bonus-action attack with +5 to the damage roll if you take the Dash action and "If you move at least 10 feet in a straight line immediately before taking this bonus action".

When playing on a grid, am I correct that you would very often be able to move around the enemy to get this benefit, often without provoking an opportunity attack?
(On a 5-foot grid, excluding obstacles, there are a minimum of 8 squares within an enemy's reach; from one diagonally adjacent square to the next are 3 squares.)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## It would work, but why would you want to?

It would be easy to circle the enemy using dash.  You don't provoke an opportunity Attack because you remain within reach.

So you would usually be able to move from one diagonal position grid to another, which is 10 feet.  For example, if the grid has north at the top and the squares are arranged north-south, east-west, this would be movement from north-east to south-east.  In doing as long as the last move was to one of the diagonal squares, you would have 10 feet of dashing.

This seems seems unusual to me, though.  There aren't any classes I can think of who would want to dash to move to a different spot next to an an enemy as their action just to gain +5 damage on a single bonus action.  Most classes that want to hit this way will have more than one attack and/or a good use for their bonus action.  This would throw them both away to get a single bonus attack at +5 damage.  It just seems unlikely.

Comment: Action dash +BA attack (+5 dmg) could work on a single attack character with mobile (a lv 4 fighter, barbarian og ranger for instance) to then move away. Or on a swashbuckler for the same effect... 5 dmg is about 1,4 SA dice or 2,8 rogue lvs dmg-wise.

Comment: does your answer change of the enemy is a gargantuan creature or if the enemy has a long reach?

Comment: @ KorvinStarmast, no I don't think so.  It would be easier to stay in front of a gargantuan creature.  I think the answer is the same though